# Cannot install 3rd party CSS framework into Vue app

Tags: css, vue.js, salesforce-lightning

I am trying to install and use the [Salesforce Lightning Design System](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/) for my apps styles. But it just doesn't work. My steps (I am using vue-cli 3.4.0 + typescript):

`npm install @salesforce-ux/design-system --save`

At first I imported it into the styles of my `App.vue`

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
@import url("/node_modules/@salesforce-ux/design-system/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css");

body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' viewBox='0 0 100 100'%3E%3Cg stroke='%23CCC' stroke-width='0' %3E%3Crect fill='%23F5F5F5' x='-60' y='-60' width='110' height='240'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
</style>
```

Then I added the classes to a simple button:

```
<button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" @click="createTask">Save</button>
```

This does nothing. Classes are applied, but no styling.

I tried adding it to my main.ts:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import store from './store';
import '../node_modules/@salesforce-ux/design-system/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css'
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

This makes the whole build fail because it says it can't resolve the module:

```
./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../node_modules/@salesforce-ux/design-system/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css' in '/usr/src/app/src'
```

This happens even though the dependency is in my `package.json` and the autocomplete in vscode shows me the relative path. I've tried diferent relative paths and none of them work. What's going on here?

Comment: Have you tried `import '@salesforce-ux/design-system/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css'` without `node_modules`

Comment: @TncAndrei Just did and this gives me `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@salesforce-ux/design-system/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.css' in '/usr/src/app/src'`

Comment: I just installed this with `npm install @salesforce-ux/design-system --save`, imported the CSS in `main.js` with `import '@salesforce-ux/design-system/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.css';` And it works. Try reinstalling the module and check the node_modules folder to make sure it installed it correctly.

Comment: :facepalm: I just realized it was because my app was running in a docker container and I needed to re-build the container to actually install the package in my docker image. Thanks for the help.